# Half installed packages and python circular dependency

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, apt, dpkg

Something went wrong while updating to ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10:

```
root@ely:/sys/bus/usb/devices# dpkg -l | grep ^i[HUFW]
iU  libpython2.7                           2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
iU  python                                 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
iU  python-all                             2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        package depending on all supported Python runtime versions
iU  python-all-dev                         2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        package depending on all supported Python development packages
iU  python-dev                             2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        header files and a static library for Python (default)
iU  python-minimal                         2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        minimal subset of the Python language (default version)
iU  python2.7                              2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
iU  python2.7-dev                          2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.7)
iF  python2.7-minimal                      2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
```

When I try to configure the packages python2.7-minimal and python-minimal, I get what looks like a circular dependency:

```
root@ely:~# sudo dpkg --configure python2.7-minimal
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7-minimal:
 python2.7-minimal depends on python-minimal (>= 2.6.6-3+squeeze1); however:
  Package python-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal


root@ely:~# sudo dpkg --configure python-minimal
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-minimal:
 python-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.3); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
```

How do I resolve those python2.7-minimal <-> python.minimal dependencies? Secondly, how do I unpack or configure the iU and iF -marked packages? I can't reconfigure nor install anything in this instance. Thanks.

Comment: Try `aptitude reinstall python2.7-dev python2.7`

Comment: I get the same errors using the aptitude reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to configure it?

```
sudo dpkg --configure python2.7-dev
```

Next time give the complete backlog or else it won't be useful.

Comment: root@ely:~# sudo dpkg --configure python2.7-minimal
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7-minimal:
 python2.7-minimal depends on python-minimal (>= 2.6.6-3+squeeze1); however:
  Package python-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal

Comment: So python2.7-minimal depends on python-minimal. However              `root@ely:~# sudo dpkg --configure python2.7-minimal
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7-minimal:
 python2.7-minimal depends on python-minimal (>= 2.6.6-3+squeeze1); however:
  Package python-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal`

Comment: ahhhh...please see the edit to the original post - python-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal while python2.7-minimal depends on python-minimal.

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian remove the outputs and add `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.